# How to cut and merge mp4 video files without re-encoding

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-editor

Using Ubuntu 18.04 I have some screencast video files in mp4 container (h.264/mp3 codecs) that I want at times merge (i.e. C.mp4 =  A.mp4+B.mp4) or at times cut removing some intervals (e.g. D.mp4 = A.mp4[0,320{seconds}]+A.mp4[325,340]+C.mp4).

I am now using kdenlive, it woks but it re-encode everything and it seems a bit too much for such a task.

Is there a simpler way to do that without re-encoding (even, and perhaps preferred, command line or stable Python/Julia/R/.. way) ?

I am thinking at something like PDFtk for the pdfs :-))

PS: I did try `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -to 00:00:10 -i test1.mp4 test2.mp4` but I have an error:

> Option to (record or transcode stop time) cannot be applied to input
>   url test1.mp4 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output
>   file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.

My files have the same container, codec and resolution.

(I know nothing of video stuff..)

EDIT: I don't want to look pessimistic, but more I look on it more I behave that what I thought to be super simple is indeed super complicate. What a pity nobody wrote a high-level interface to perform something like that.. I'm sure I am not the first one with such a need..

EDIT2: I found [moviepy](https://pypi.org/project/moviepy/), but it is still far from my original idea (it re-encodes and it has longer than needed API..  I can script it but the reencoding problem remains):

```
pip install moviepy

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
c1 = VideoFileClip("test1.mp4").subclip(0,5)
c2 = VideoFileClip("test1.mp4").subclip(10,15)
f = concatenate_videoclips([c1,c2])
f.write_videofile(test2.mp4)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with ffmpeg. You need to order the options properly and add two more:

```
ffmpeg -i INFILE.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:01:00.000 -t 00:00:10.000 OUTFILE.mp4
```

From [here](https://vollnixx.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/howto-cut-a-video-directly-with-ffmpeg-without-transcoding/).

Comment: Note that `-t` is for desired *duration*. You can alternatively use `-to` in place of `-t` for *end-time*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as posted in my own question this doesn't solve the problem of the re-encoding, but at least it is a handy interface. Just use it with

```
vcat -i inputfile1,inputfile2[start-end],... -o <outputfile>
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, getopt, re

def printerror(errormsg):
  print("*** vcat - concatenate video segments using moviepy ***\n")
  print("ERROR:", errormsg,"\n")
  print("Usage: vcat -i inputfile1,inputfile2[start-end],... -o <outputfile>")
  print("Optional start and end points should be given in seconds. If files have spaces should be quoted (e.g. \"input file.mp4[5-30]\").")

try:
 from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
except ImportError:
 printerror("You don't seem to have moviepy installed. Install it with `pip install moviepy`.")
 exit(1)

def main(argv):
    inputfiles_arg = ''
    outputfile = ''
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["input=","output="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        printerror(str(err))
        sys.exit(2)
    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt == '-h':
            printerror("")
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in ("-i", "--input"):
            inputfiles_arg = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--output"):
            outputfile = arg
    if outputfile =='':
        printerror("Output file not specified")

    iFiles = inputfiles_arg.split(',')

    clips=[]
    for iFile in iFiles:
        subclip = re.search(r"\[([0-9\-\.]+)\]", iFile)
        if subclip is None:
            clips.append(VideoFileClip(iFile))
        else:
            dims = subclip.group(1).split('-')
            if len(dims) != 2:
                printerror("If a specific segment of a file is specified, this should be given as [startseconds-endseconds]")
            iFile = iFile.replace("["+subclip.group(1)+"]",'')
            clips.append(VideoFileClip(iFile).subclip(float(dims[0]),float(dims[1])))

    f = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
    f.write_videofile(outputfile)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Disclaimer: I don't use Python by a while, so sure there could be better approaches.. bdw it's really nice to be able to do what you want to do in a few hours because of the enormous documentation you can find on the net about python..